# Nested optimization problem - Function approximation

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization, interpolation, approximation, maximum

I need to maximize the following function (the input to `NMaximize` below)

```
    NMaximize[{((1/3) + f[p]*(1 - p)*(((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2-1))/(1+(1-p)*
    (((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2 - 1)), p >= Sqrt[2]/2, p <= 1}, {p}]
```

where $f(\cdot)$ is defined as follows

```
    f[p_?NumericQ] := NMinimize[{-((a + a^2 + b - 2 a b + b^2 + c - 2 a c - 2 b c + c^2)
    /((-1 + a) (a + b + c))), 0 <= a, a <= b, b <= c, c <= 1, c <= a + b, (a + b + c)/3 <= p}, 
    {a, b, c}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"][[1]]
```

However, as expected, the computation does not end ,and there are several alert messages. Considering the underlying mathematical problem I am trying to solve, I could replace $f(\cdot)$ by a simple function $g(\cdot)$ that approximates it, but I need $g(p)\le f(p)$ for all $p\in[0,1]$. I tried to use `InterpolatingPolynomial` with a few values of $f(\cdot)$. However, $f(\cdot)$ is neither concave nor convex in $[0,1]$. I am struggling to obtain a good approximation of $f(\cdot)$ which satisfies the $g(p)\le f(p)$ in $[0,1]$.

How can we generate such approximation function $g(\cdot)$ (alternately, can we solve this optimization problem in a different way)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extremum of a polytope usually saturates a few of its inequalities, in this case $(a + b + c)/3 = p$ and $b=c$. With this we can find $f(p)$ exactly:

```
Minimize[{-((a + a^2 + b - 2 a b + b^2 + c - 2 a c - 2 b c + 
          c^2)/((-1 + a) (a + b + c))),
          0 <= a, a <= b, b == c, c <= 1, c <= a + b, (a + b + c)/3 == p},
         {a, b, c}]
(*    complicated result, the important part of which is    *)
```

$$
f(p) = \frac{2(p-1+\sqrt{1-p})}{p}
$$
from which the exact answer follows:

```
Maximize[{(1/3 - (2 (-1 + p) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - p] + p) (-1 + 2 p^2))/p)/(p + 2 p^2 - 2 p^3),
         1/Sqrt[2] < p < 1}, p] // RootReduce

(*    {0.348695341134874, {p -> 0.8151520693995784}}    *)
```

These numbers are given as [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects, which I've converted to numerical representation here with [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html).

Comment: Thank you @Roman , this solution is very interesting! Could you please explain me how we can be sure that for this specific optimization problem the minimum is attained when $b=c$ (i.e., that the inequality saturated is precisely $b\le c$) ? I have the feeling there is something obvious I am missing... I would be very happy if you could provide a brief clarification about it. Thanks.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati I have no proof but combined two observations non-rigorously: (1) the extrema of a function in a [polytope-shaped region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope) are usually on the polytope's surface, not its interior, which means that some of your inequalities will be saturated by the solution, and (2) by inspection I noticed that the numerical solutions $f(p)$ indeed saturate $b=c$ and $a+b+c=3p$. Concerning (1): there are numerous counter-examples, so it's just a hint; for example, $x^2$ on $[-1,1]$ is minimal in the interior, and maximal on the surface.

Comment: Thank you @Roman, I see. I am trying now to rigorously prove this claim, so that I will be able to use this solution to have an analytical result (which is one of the reasons I like it). Maybe it is not difficult.

Comment: I tried your solution, and I thought of obtaining a step-by-step solution either with Mathematica or Wolfram Pro Premium. However, it seems that the step-by-step solution is not present for minimization problems. Could you please explain me how to obtain the steps for solving this problem (in the way you showed) @Roman ?

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati this isn't the right forum for questions about step-by-step solutions or proofs. Please ask at the [mathematics stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: OK @Roman, thank you for the information!

Comment: According with your procedure @Roman, shouldn't we use a function $f(p)$ equal to $2((p-1+\sqrt{1-p})/p$ (as you wrote) **only for** $p\in[\sqrt{2}/2,8/9]$ and equal to $(4-3 p)/(3 p)$ for $p\in[8/9,1]$? Shouldn't we finally plug this *piecewise-defined function* into the maximization problem, instead of just using $2((p-1+\sqrt{1-p})/p$ for the whole interval $[\sqrt{2}/2,1]$?

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati you're right; but we already know approximately where the optimum lies (from the numerical answers) and so I took a shortcut.

Comment: Ah OK @Roman, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I make a slight adjustment to `f[p]`, to restrict `a` so as to prevent the denominator from vanishing. Also it is faster in general to use `FindMinValue` and will likely work just as well for present purposes.

```
f[p_?NumericQ] := 
 FindMinValue[{-((a + a^2 + b - 2 a b + b^2 + c - 2 a c - 2 b c + 
        c^2)/((-1 + a) (a + b + c))), 0 <= a <= .99, a <= b, b <= c, 
   c <= 1, c <= a + b, (a + b + c)/3 <= p}, {a, b, c}]
```

I think the idea of using an interpolation is sound and will improve speed.

```
gvals = Table[{p, g[p]}, {p, Sqrt[2]/2., 1., .001}];
interp = Interpolation[gvals];
```

Now maximize:

```
In[2018]:= FindMaximum[{((1/3) + 
     interp[p]*(1 - p)*(((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2 - 1))/(1 + (1 - 
        p)*(((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2 - 1)), p >= Sqrt[2]/2, p <= 1}, {p}]

(* Out[2018]= {0.348695, {p -> 0.815155}} *)
```

Comment: Nice, we confirm one another.

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution. I am sorry, I did not understand how we can be sure that `interp[p]`$\le$`f[p]` for all $p$ in the considered interval, as required in the question text.

Comment: Furthermore, in this problem I am also interested in the case $a$ approaches $1$. Do you think there is anything we can do for studying this case too?

Answer (score 4):

Realizing your idea concerning the interpolation and correcting your syntax (`&&` instead of `,` in the constraints), I obtain

```
f[p_?NumericQ] :=  NMinimize[{-((a + a^2 + b - 2 a b + b^2 + c - 2 a c - 2 b c + 
      c^2)/((-1 + a) (a + b + c))), 
 0 <= a && a <= b && b <= c && c <= 1 && 
  c <= a + b && (a + b + c)/3 <= p}, {a, b, c}, 
Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
PrecisionGoal -> 4][[1]];
if = Interpolation[Table[{p, f[p]}, {p, 0.7, 1, 0.05}]];
NMaximize[{((1/3) + 
 if[p]*(1 - p)*(((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2 - 1))/(1 + (1 - 
    p)*(((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2 - 1)), p >= Sqrt[2]/2 && p <= 1}, {p}]

(*{0.348699, {p -> 0.815213}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction and for the proposed solution. I did not understand how can we be sure that `if[p]`$\le$`f[p]` for all $p$ in the considered interval, as required in the question text.

Comment: @PenelopeBeneti: I think the condition `if[p]<=f[p]` is not of importance for solving the problem under consideration.It is important that the difference `RealAb[if[p]-f[p]]` may be done uniformly arbitrary small on the interval $[0.7,1]$. The base of that statement needs in  analysis of differential properties of `f[p]`..

Comment: I understand what you mean @user64494 and I thank you again because I could learn from your solution. In my question there is that constraint because in the proof I am writing, I need to use a *lower bound* of $f()$ to provide a *lower bound* of the  maximum I am computing with `NMaximize`. In other words, I cannot *state* that the maximum is **at least** $0.348699$ if the approximation function `if[]` is, for some values, *strictly* larger than than $f()$, because the real maximum could be *smaller* (e.g., 0.348698; BTW Roman and Akku14 obtained 0.348695...).

Comment: Finally, if one could verify that for a certain number of points (e.g., the ones you choose : `{p, 0.7, 1, 0.05}`), that we have `if[x]<=f[x]` **for all** $x$ in the considered interval, than I would be sure that the result of the maximization is lower bounded by $0.348699$. To further clarify, I would content myself to state that the maximization result is *at least* $0.347$, **if** was sure about it.

Answer (score 3):

Let me use a little trick to get an anylytical solution.

Since Minimize can't find minimum depending on variable p with `(a + b + c)/3 <= p` , set p to a mathematical constant (here `p -> 2/E`  , that is within alowed p values.

I know, of course, you have to test later with other methods, wether this is valid, but i made experience, it often works well.

```
{min, varsmin} = 
  Minimize[{-((a + a^2 + b - 2 a b + b^2 + c - 2 a c - 2 b c + 
     c^2)/((-1 + a) (a + b + c))), 0 <= a, a <= b, b <= c,   c <= 1,
 c <= a + b, (a + b + c)/3 <= 2/E}, {a, b, c}];

f[p_] = min /. E -> 2/p // FullSimplify

(*   2 (1 + Sqrt[(1 - p)/p^2] - 1/p)   *)

Plot[f[p], {p, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}]

nmax = NMaximize[{((1/3) + 
  f[p]*(1 - p)*(((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2 - 1))/(1 + (1 - 
     p)*(((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2 - 1)), p >= Sqrt[2]/2, 
   p <= 1}, {p}]

(*   {0.348695, {p -> 0.815152}}   *)
```

Analytical solution

```
max = Maximize[{((1/3) + 
   f[p]*(1 - p)*(((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2 - 1))/(1 + (1 - 
      p)*(((1/(Sqrt[2]/2))*p)^2 - 1)), p >= Sqrt[2]/2, 
 p <= 1}, {p}] // FullSimplify

(*   {Root[40292242 - 521152218 #1 + 2609177160 #1^2 - 6515590038 #1^3 + 
8910881883 #1^4 - 7184393418 #1^5 + 3522825570 #1^6 - 
1014076554 #1^7 + 147469221 #1^8 - 8264916 #1^9 + 34992 #1^10 &, 
3], {p -> 
Root[-48 - 296 #1 + 269 #1^2 + 2044 #1^3 - 2940 #1^4 - 60 #1^5 + 
  1176 #1^6 + 144 #1^8 - 432 #1^9 + 144 #1^10 &, 4]}}   *)

max // N[#, 50] &

(*   {0.34869534113486204014442063948484350125554473832604, {p -> 
 0.81515206939957835833133995379472132118970645053175}}   *)
```

Comment: Sometimes that trick works, sometimes doesn't. I don't see how to ground it.

Comment: The reason why MInimize or Solve or Reduce in simular cases fails, is, that checking all conditions for a free variable p is quite difficult. Using a mathematical constant, you circumvent the built in conditional checking routines. Then of course you have to do that condtional checking by hand with other methods. Ultimate check is whether result is right.

Comment: I like your approach @Akku14 . Unfortunately my software never ends running the first input command. Do you think it happens because I have Wolfram|Alpha Notebook Edition (https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-alpha-notebook-edition)? I have another question. You provided an analytical solution as Roman. Why your solution is different from his solution (starting from the 14th digit)?

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati, may be WolframAlpha is not as mighty as Mathematica in this case. Applying `// N[#, 50] & ` to both, i find no difference between Roman's and my result.

Comment: Thank you @Akku14 . I am afraid I need to buy Mathematica because Notebook is not sufficient...